# Let $p$ be an odd prime, and $f(x):=x^{p^2-p} -1+(x+1)^p.(x+2)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Solve $f(x)\equiv0\pmod p.$

Find the number of incongruent solutions of Solve $f(x)\equiv0\pmod{p^2}.$

I think i can raise solutions to the second one from the first one by Hensel's Lemma but i am not sure how to do the first part. Any help?

Comment: $(x+1)^p\equiv x+1\pmod p$

Comment: I know that bit but this part $x^{p^2-p}$ confuses me @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I did that for 0,1,2,..,p-1 but couldnt figure out what to do next  @MonsieurGalois

Comment: Sorry, first I thought you wanted to prove that $f(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's quit first the case when $p\mid x$: If this happens, you can just delete the $x$ in all the equation and see if the result is $0$ mod $p$. So it becomes:

$$f(x)= -1+(1)^p\cdot(2)=-1+2=1\not\equiv 0\pmod p$$

Now if $p\not\mid x$:

First let's see that $x^{p^2-p}=(x^{p-1})^p$ and by the [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$, (because $\gcd(x,p)=1$) So you will get that $(x^{p-1})^p\equiv 1^p\equiv 1 \pmod p$. Now you can do the next step:

$$f(x)\equiv 1-1+(x+1)^p\cdot(x+2)\equiv (x+1)(x+2)$$

And the only cases you must solve are when $x+1\equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $x+2\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

So $x\equiv -1,-2\pmod p$ are your solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it pretty clear now!